# serialization of chess game

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, chess

hello everyone,
               IN JAVA... I am writing a chess code. In that chess code,, GAME is the main class .It composes BOARD class,and that BOARD composes classes KING,QUEEN, BISHOP,KNIGHT,ROOK.and these classes KING,QUEEN, BISHOP,KNIGHT,ROOK extends PIECSES. so now i want to save the game and play it afterwards.i have read the concept serializing but i am not getting how to implement it and to which class should i write " implements Serializable".i also have static variables in my code.
will coping the static variable into normal variable before serialization and copy it back to static variable after deserialization help? THANK YOU...

Comment: Rather than serializing a whole game, have you considered saving the game in a pgn file?

Comment: no,i want it particularly serialized. thank you for your interest.